# return an information if the key is not in the mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with multiples parameters and I would like that mongoose return a message if a parameter is unknown.

Example if I have name and age, if age is not required but the user write agge, I would like return a warning for the user but I did not find that in the mongoose doc.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you write code in backend, don't write what you didn't need.

For example you schema like this :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age:String //not required
```

and your rest API

```
app.post('/user', (req,res) => {
 const newData = new UserSchema({
  name : req.body.name
  //although user post age, don't create age field, ignore that
 })
 newData.save().then().catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Another way, create validation, if user input age, send respons('not required').

I hope this clue can help you. Thank you